# Create tag element dynamically and apply styles

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created `"myCanvas"` div element dynamically and try to set styles to the div tag it throw the  undefined exception. Please check my code and suggest me

```
// move the canvas, so it's contained by the same parent as the image
    var imgParent = img.parentNode;
    $('<div id="myCanvas">');
    var can = $('myCanvas');
    can.appendTo(imgParent);

    // position it over the image
    can.style.left = x + 'px'; //If set styles to can element, it's styles is undefined
```

What i did wrong here.. ? please anyone suggest me a right things..

Thanks,

Bharathi

Comment: not `$('myCanvas');`..it should be `$('#myCanvas');`

Comment: you missed # in jquery selector $("#myCanvas");

Answer (score 2):

Make is simple:

```
$('<div id="myCanvas">').appendTo(img.parentNode).css('left', x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var can = $('myCanvas');
```

with

```
var can = $('#myCanvas');
```

***[edit user="dholakiyaankit"]***

QA asking for id not class

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select the myCanvas element because it hasn't been added to the DOM just yet (your selector wasn't right either). You can use this instead:

```
var imgParent = img.parentNode;
// By default when creating an element in jQuery, it returns an instance of the jQuery object created
var can = $('<div id="myCanvas">');
can.appendTo(imgParent);
can.style.left = x + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

Antegias response should read

Replace ... with :

```
var can = $('#myCanvas');
```

as you have given it an id not a class, you cant select it in this way till its added to DOM, but you have a reference to it anyway in the variable can